Is every finite inner regular measure is also outer regular?
Suppose that $\mu:\mathfrak{B}(X)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a finite measure with $\mathfrak{B}(X)$ denoting the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a Hausdorff space $X$. We say that $\mu$ is inner regular if
$$\mu(B)=\sup\{\mu (K):K\subseteq B  \text{ is compact})\}$$ for any $B\in \mathfrak{B}(X)$ and we say that $\mu$ is outer regular if
$$\mu(B)=\inf\{\mu (U):U\supseteq B  \text{ is open})\}$$
for any $B\in \mathfrak{B}(X)$.
Is every finite inner regular measure also outer regular?
The answer is yes if you use that result that is in my previous question (see this link). Since, I'm not really sure if that result is correct (I'm uncertain because I didn't find this result in any book I looked at), I also not sure if every finite inner regular measure is outer regular.

Note that $X$ is Hausdorff, so $K$ compact implies $K$ closed. Then, $K^c$ is open, further, since $M :=\mu(X) < \infty$, you also have that $\mu(K^c) = M - \mu(K)$. Then, assuming inner regularity,
$$\mu(B)=\sup\{ \mu(K) : K \subseteq B \ \text{ is compact} \} \\ = \sup\{ M - \mu(K^c) : K \subseteq B \ \text{ is compact} \} \\ \leq M - \inf \{\mu(U) : U \supseteq B^c \ \text{ is open}\}$$
where the last inequality follows from the fact that the all $K \subseteq B$ gives the open set $K^c$, but not every open set $U \supseteq B^c$ gives a compact set, when considering $U^c$. As a result
$$\mu(B^c) \leq\inf \{\mu(U) : U \supseteq B^c \ \text{ is open}\} \leq M - \mu(B) = \mu(B^c)$$
Thus $\mu$ outer regular.

Thank you very much!
